# Configure mail relay on Red Hat

Tags: redhat, sendmail, solaris

i have a red hat linux server which cannot send outgoing emails.
i also have a solaris server which already cofigured before to relay
mails to the mail server.
to enable user receive email from red hat, i need to relay mail through the solaris server.
And my boss strictly asked me to using sendmail instead postfix.

so far, this is what i do:

solaris server :
bres.net.com - 192.65.7.8

red hat:
hostname : batman
ip : 192.55.7.43

**Edit /etc/mail/sendmail.mc**

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`bres.net.com')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`net.com')dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.net.com)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(batman.net.com)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(others.net.com)dnl
```

**Edit /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       batman.net.com localhost.localdomain  localhost  batman
192.55.7.43     batman    batman.net.com   loghost
192.65.7.8      bres      bres.net.com
```

**Edit /etc/resolv.conf**

```
search net.com
bres.net.com  192.65.7.8
```

**Create new sendmail.cf :**

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
```

**Restart sendmail**

**Test it by try sending mail**

**Check log /var/log/maillog**

```
Nov 22 12:00:54 localhost sendmail[22251]: uAM402ru022251: from=root, size=591, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611220400.uAM402ru022251@batman.net.com>, relay=root@localhost
Nov 22 12:02:54 localhost sendmail[22281]: uAM40sRm022281: from=<root@batman.net.com >, size=863, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611220400.uAM402ru022251@batman.net.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=batman.net.com[127.0.0.1]    
Nov 22 12:02:54 localhost sendmail[22251]: uAM402ru022251: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:02:52, xdelay=00:02:00, mailer=relay, pri=30591, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (uAM40sRm022281 Message accepted for delivery)
Nov 22 12:04:14 localhost sendmail[22303]: uAM40sRm022281: to=<root@batman.net.com>, delay=00:01:20, xdelay=00:01:20, mailer=relay, pri=120863, relay=bres.net.com, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Name server: bres.net.com: host name lookup failure
```

After change define(`SMART_HOST',`192.65.7.8')dnl =, the log show as below:

```
Nov 23 09:51:49 batman sendmail[8953]: uAN1m5aZ008953: from=<root@batman.net.com>, size=1052, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611222200.uAMM02K3007934@batman.net.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=batman.net.com [127.0.0.1]
Nov 23 09:51:49 batman sm-msp-queue[8950]: uAMM02K3007934: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=03:51:47, xdelay=00:03:44, mailer=relay, pri=120780, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (uAN1m5aZ008953 Message accepted for delivery)
Nov 23 09:51:49 batman sendmail[8964]: uAN1m5aZ008953: to=<root@batman.net.com>, ctladdr=<root@batman.net.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31276, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Nov 23 09:51:49 batman sendmail[8953]: uAN1m5ab008953: from=<root@batman.net.com>, size=3002, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611222002.uAMK2UOH007318@batman.net.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=batman.net.com [127.0.0.1]
Nov 23 09:51:49 batman sm-msp-queue[8950]: uAMK2UOH007318: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=05:49:19, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=122704, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (uAN1m5ab008953 Message accepted for delivery)
Nov 23 09:51:49 batman sendmail[8966]: uAN1m5ab008953: to=<root@batman.net.com>, ctladdr=<root@batman.net.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=33231, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Nov 23 09:54:11 batman sendmail[8962]: uAN1oRWw008962: from=root, size=66, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611230150.uAN1oRWw008962@batman.net.com>, relay=root@localhost
Nov 23 09:54:11 batman sendmail[8962]: uAN1oRWw008962: to=kelly@net.com, delay=00:03:44, mailer=esmtp, pri=30066, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
```

I can relay email by changed the define SMARTHOST and add one config file(service.switch) at etc/mail.

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`relay:[192.65.7.8]')dnl
```

**add service.switch at etc/mail**

```
####### start of file #########

hosts files
aliases files

####### end of file ###########
```

After changes, the mail relay working perfectly fine. But after red hat server restart, the sendmail not working and the logs shows as below:

```
Nov 25 10:00:30 batman sendmail[15372]: uAP20Ude015372: from=root, size=66,class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611250200.uAP20Ude015372@batman.net.com>, relay=root@localhost
Nov 25 10:00:30 batman sendmail[15372]: uAP20Ude015372: to=kelly@net.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30066,relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

and before this log, the log show:

```
Nov 24 10:09:47 batman sendmail[24936]: uAO29kOL024936: ruleset=check_rcpt, arg1=<root@batman.net.com>, relay=[192.65.7.8], reject=450 4.4.0 <root@batman.net.com>... Relaying temporarily denied. Cannot resolve PTR record for 192.65.7.8
```

The log show connection refused and Cannot resolve PTR record. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

*"Host name lookup failure"* indicates a  DNS error, not necessarily a sendmail misconfiguration.

Sendmail, or rather sending email heavily depends on DNS and does not play well with hosts and domains that only exist as entries in the `/etc/hosts` file.

The simplest would be to ensure that `nslookup bres.net.com` works.

Maybe it's the formatting of your question, but the entry `bres.net.com 192.65.7.8` does not belong in a `resolv.conf` and there should be an entry `nameserver <IP-address of nameserver>` in there as well.  A simple resolv.conf looks like:

```
#/etc/resolv.conf
domain example.com
search example.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
options attempts:2
```

You might try and use the IP-address of the smarthost rather than a hostname as well to avoid some DNS issues:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`[192.65.7.8]')dnl
```

Comment: Actually, i can ping bres.net.com. Can you please explain more bres.net.com 192.65.7.8 does not belong in a resolv.conf and there should be an entry nameserver <IP-address of nameserver> in there as well.?thanks

Comment: hi, i ve already changed by using ip address but the log show different from before. Updated at the question.

Comment: An sendmail log entry `stat=Sent (<id> Message accepted for delivery)` typically indicates succes. Are messages delivered or still sitting in the queue (check as root with `mailq`)

Comment: yesterday, it work perfectly fine.changes update at question. but today, after restart the server,  the log show connection refused from localhost and cannot send email.